# How do I open a filtered list page from the infolog with one of the SysInfoAction classes

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

How do I open a filtered list page from the infolog with one of the SysInfoAction classes?

I try this:

```
static void infoSO(Args _args)
{  
    Query         q = new Query();

    #define.SalesPool('Test')

    q.addDataSource(tableNum(SalesTable)).addRange(
        fieldNum(SalesTable, SalesPoolId)).value(SysQuery::value(#salesPool));

    info('bla', '', SysInfoAction_FormrunQuery::newFormnameQuery(formStr(SalesTableListPage), q));
}
```

And I get the following error:

The required QueryBuildDataSource was not found in the Query associated with the FormDataSource '%1'. The QueryBuildDataSource should have the same name and table ID as the FormDataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the error you can change your code as follows:

```
static void infoSO(Args _args)
{
   Query         q = new Query(queryStr(SalesTableListPage));

    #define.SalesPool('Test')

    q.dataSourceTable(tableNum(SalesTable)).addRange(
        fieldNum(SalesTable, SalesPoolId)).value(SysQuery::value(#salesPool));

    info('bla', '', SysInfoAction_FormrunQuery::newFormnameQuery(formStr(SalesTableListPage), q));
}
```

P.S. Instead of opening a list page I would suggest to open the sales order details form.

Comment: Thanks, that works. The idea was to display multiple Sales orders in a single screen that's why I wanted to do this for a ListPage.

Comment: The SalesTable form also has both Grid View and Details View.